# How to process annotations at runtime?

Tags: java, annotations

I'm building a data model and I need to define an annotation like @UNIQUE so whenever the model is being filled it first runs a code to check the database to see if it is unique or not.My database is not relational and does not support Unique indexes so doing it in database is out the question.
What I need to know is there a way to write annotations logic to check this constraint at runtime?

Example

```
public class model{
    @Unique
    public CustomKey key;
}
```

Now I want when the model is being filled and sees this Unique annotation it automatically first call the code below before continuing : 
(The following is sudo code not actual java code)

```
public void checkUnique(){
    if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
        Unique myAnnotation = (Unique) annotation;
        checkifIsUnquie(myAnnotation.getVariableValue());
    }
```

Comment: What do you not specifically understand? How to access annotations via reflection?

Comment: @VinceEmigh No.I will edit my post now so you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

***Regarding Reflection***

Check this project: https://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Include it in your project, and use the code block below to get a list of all fields annotated by an annotation:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

Set<Field> annotated = 
           reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

Also note that you need to declare your annotation class, namely, @Unique to be retained to runtime, otherwise javac will strip the annotation information on any field you annotated. Here's how you do it:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Unique { }
```

***But you actually need AOP (Aspect oriented programming) for doing this***

since in Java, you cannot intercept code flow using annotation alone. In pure Java, annotation is just a piece of information tied to a class, field etc. that you can query during compilation-time, runtime... And you have to define logic to process them yourself.  Check AspectJ as a Java AOP library/runtime, which could allow you to do what you want.